# Why is the MZ DOS Header Signature 0x54AD in PE files?

Tags: hex, file-format, portable-executable

I have recently started with the `PE(Portable Executable)` file format, more specifically `PE/COFF`. I was reading a tutorial by **Randy Kath** [here](http://www.csn.ul.ie/~caolan/pub/winresdump/winresdump/doc/pefile2.html).

When I was reading through the structure of MZ DOS header, I found that MZ DOS header was verified using the signature in `e_magic` field. The structure is as follows:

```
typedef struct _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER {  // DOS .EXE header
    USHORT e_magic;         // Magic number
    USHORT e_cblp;          // Bytes on last page of file
    USHORT e_cp;            // Pages in file
    USHORT e_crlc;          // Relocations
    USHORT e_cparhdr;       // Size of header in paragraphs
    USHORT e_minalloc;      // Minimum extra paragraphs needed
    USHORT e_maxalloc;      // Maximum extra paragraphs needed
    USHORT e_ss;            // Initial (relative) SS value
    USHORT e_sp;            // Initial SP value
    USHORT e_csum;          // Checksum
    USHORT e_ip;            // Initial IP value
    USHORT e_cs;            // Initial (relative) CS value
    USHORT e_lfarlc;        // File address of relocation table
    USHORT e_ovno;          // Overlay number
    USHORT e_res[4];        // Reserved words
    USHORT e_oemid;         // OEM identifier (for e_oeminfo)
    USHORT e_oeminfo;       // OEM information; e_oemid specific
    USHORT e_res2[10];      // Reserved words
    LONG   e_lfanew;        // File address of new exe header
  } IMAGE_DOS_HEADER, *PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER;
```

and the tutorial says :

> All MS-DOS-compatible executable files set this value to 0x54AD,
>   which represents the ASCII characters MZ.

My question is the same.

The ascii value of `M` and `Z` is `77` and `90` respectively, which translates to `4D` and `5A` in hexadecimal. How does `0x54AD` represent `MZ`?

It may be a silly question. But do help me understand if its too silly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the source that claims the signature is `0x54AD` is wrong; `MZ` in hex is actually `0x5A4D` (for little-endian architectures), as evidenced by the output of this program:

```
#include <Windows.h> // for the USHORT type
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    USHORT MZ = ('M' | 'Z' << 8);
    printf("0x%.4hX\n", MZ);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x5A4D
```

You might still have the question, why does the byte for `'Z'` (`5A`) come first when the signature is actually `'MZ'`?

This is to do with endianness, which is the order in which bytes are stored in individual halfwords, words, doublewords, and so on.

Big-endian stores bytes with the most significant byte in the highest memory address, and little-endian is the opposite, storing the most significant byte in the least significant memory address.

The x86 and x64 architectures are little-endian, so the most significant byte in `MZ` (i.e. the `Z`) comes first.